# Which kind of memory do I need for this laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade the RAM in my laptop.  It has two slots, but only 1 is filled with a 4gb stick, so I am looking for another 4gb to stick in the other slot.  It is a HP g6-1d38dx.

I found this RAM, 9-9-9-24, but it is 1333mhz.   Looks like it says my max bandwith on the stock stick is 800MhZ.  Would that still be cool to use since it is more than the max?

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820576005

Also will mixing and matching brands have much of an effect?  Can someone link a proper module for my machine?

[image: ram1]

[image: ram2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandwidth and frequency are two different things. Your ram is DDR3 1600 with 9-9-9-24 timings. This corsair dimm should work just fine, considering it's all the exact same specs. Personally, I would order two of them simply to ensure no differences, but that's just me.

Mix matching brands shouldn't hurt you, considering all specs are the same between products.

Comment: I bought 2 of these see how it goes

Comment: You should be all good with them. Corsair makes good memory, and with a matching pair, you can't go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Memory Advisor Tool](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/advisor) from Crucial (you can even install a small piece of software that will scan your computer and give you recommendations). It has worked great for me in the past.

If you have trouble with this try [this](http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/PC-Memory/Laptop-Memory/QF275AA?HP-4GB-DDR3-1333-Laptop-PC-Memory).

Comment: Yea saw this before I asked but unfortunately couldn't find my model on there.

Comment: Did you try the system scanner? 
http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00820047&tmp_track_link=ot_faqs/top_issues/en_us/c00820047/loc:5&cc=us&dlc=en&enc=UTF-8&lc=en&product=5249650

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit operating system? Windows 7? If not I think that 4gb might be your max.

Comment: I tried the system scanner, but I can tell it doesn't return the right model.  The HP article doesn't actually link to anywhere to buy it, just says how to replace it.  Also I use Win7 x64 and Ubuntu GNU/Linux x64.

Comment: This should work for you.
http://www.shopping.hp.com/en_US/home-office/-/products/PC-Memory/Laptop-Memory/QF275AA?HP-4GB-DDR3-1333-Laptop-PC-Memory

Comment: PS: The link was on that page under: Ordering replacement RAM memory

Answer (score 1):

Some memory manufacturers have tools you can run that find the memory you need. Run the application from the computer you want to buy memory: for example [Crucial System Scanner Tool](http://www.crucial.com/). There are memory sticks that are meant to run together (dual)... depends on computer

Do you have a x64 OS? If you do than you can add more memory than 4gb otherwise it does not matter.